# Legrand switch invert light

Tags: light

[image]

[image]

Here are two photos of the switch I need help. So basically I want to change the left light to the right one and the right to the left but I don't understand the brown cables. Which ones do I need to change?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use the *Image* link to add pictures (or links to pictures). Who tells me the link you posted is safe? Searching on ibb.co gives lots of hits how to remove the ibb.co **virus**...

Comment: Based on the markings on the back, I think you want to rotate the wires 180 degrees.

Comment: do all 4 brown wires go into the wall?

Comment: why don't you simply turn the device upside down?

Comment: All wires go into the wall.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis what do you mean 180 degrees? Swapping them?

Comment: Are these 2-way switches?